# TypeError: elements.map is not a function, even though elements is an array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

`TypeError: elements.map is not a function`.Here, `elements` is an array,

```
function ListSelectCourses(props){

    const elements = props.elements;
    console.log(Array.isArray(elements))
    const listElements = elements.map((element) =>
    <option key = {element.catalog_num}>
        {element.catalog_num}
    </option>
    );
    return (
        <h3>{props.category}
            <select 
            value = {props.selected}
            onChange = {props.handleChange}>
            <option defaultValue> 
            </option>
                {listElements}
            </select> 
        </h3>
    )
};
```

The console output is true. The data from console.log(elements):

Array(2) 
0: {id: 190332, title: "Legal Ethics", term: "2019 Fall", school: "LAW", catalog_num: "802-L", …} 
1: {id: 190333, title: "Ethics", term: "2019 Fall", school: "LAW", catalog_num: "803E", …}

Comment: Can you please post the sample data from props.elements

Comment: You should make sure `elements` is always an array. Most likely you hand something wrong to your `ListSelectCourses` component. Maybe on the first render and it isn't initialized correctly.

Comment: What does `console.log(Array.isArray(elements))` output?

Comment: The output is true. The data from console.log(elements): Array(2)
0: {id: 190332, title: "Legal Ethics", term: "2019 Fall", school: "LAW", catalog_num: "802-L", …}
1: {id: 190333, title: "Ethics", term: "2019 Fall", school: "LAW", catalog_num: "803E", …}

Comment: They might be a collection of nodes instead of a true array, where are you generating `elements`?  Try this to see if coercing the value into an array changes anything `const listElements = [...elements].map((element) => ...`

Comment: @LoremIpsum updated

Comment: @Selva updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the issue was not with this component, but with another component that I thought that I had copied over.